# LOAD DATA INFILE - mySQL Error Code: 1261. Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

Tags: mysql

I am leveraging LOAD DATA INFILE to import a massive CSV file (~30 GB). There are some fields with no data and as a result I'm getting the following error code:

```
Error Code: 1261. Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

I would rather not try and edit the CSV file first due to its size. I had tried recreating the table with DEFAULT NULL for the column with the blank fields however I'm still getting the same error. Appreciate any help for a work-around on this.

Here is the create table

```
#c.execute("CREATE TABLE dns_part2_b (date VARCHAR(15), time VARCHAR(25), ip1 VARCHAR(20), ip2 VARCHAR(20), dns VARCHAR(150), arec VARCHAR(10), wsa VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL)")
```

And the LOAD DATA command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Volumes/data/mycsv.csv' INTO TABLE dns_part2_b FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

this is an example of an incomplete record:

```
date,time,ip1,ip2,dns,arec,wsa
2013-07-01,00:00:14.301038+00:00,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,domain.com,A
```

and a complete one

```
date,time,ip1,ip2,dns,arec,wsa
2013-07-01,00:00:12.335246+00:00,2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1,WPAD,NB,(WS)
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the _amount_ of fields can vary per line? 'cause that would indeed be a problem `LOAD DATA INFILE` cannot solve for you. Normally, _empty_ fields are not a problem, but _no_ fields definitely are.

Comment: the amount of fields is static. The last column only has data in it occasionally.

Comment: Could you share (1) a complete line, (2) an incomplete line (3) your exact `LOAD DATA` statement and (4) your table definition? Makes it quite a lot easier to debug this for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the right number of commas in every line.

```
date,time,ip1,ip2,dns,arec,wsa
2013-07-01,00:00:14.301038+00:00,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,domain.com,A,
```

If the dns field was missing instead it would be (for instance)

```
2013-07-01,00:00:12.335246+00:00,2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1,,NB,(WS)
```